# Don't use admin rights by default on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

On my work computer, I'm currently in the admin user group, and whenever I run tasks using `run`, it automatically tries to run the task in admin mode, even for tasks that don't require it. Normally, I would just create a new non-admin user account, and only use the admin account for admin tasks, but I can't create new users at work.

Is there a way  I can self-limit my account, and only run things as admin when I explicitly say so?

Comment: Have you asked your IT department for assistance on this?

Comment: Wow, this is exactly OPPOSITE of what everyone always asks for. :)  If you're an admin on your computer, why can't you create a local non-admin user on that system?  Have you tried asking your IT staff to make you a non-admin user you can use?

Comment: Did you change something in your UAC settings? And what do you mean by using `run`?

Comment: @Rik I suppose he's referring to Start Menu > Run (or the same dialog from Task Manager). Putting aside the local user creation, it is an interesting question nonetheless. **Is running as admin limiting in any way?**

Comment: @user886596 - If your unable to create a new local user as an local `Administrator` then you don't actuall have Administrator permissions.  The behavior you describe likely is a group policy.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I didn't know "Start Menu > Run" still existed in Windows 7. As for running via another "run" it depends if that has the option set to always "Run as administrator". If that's not the case it could be that UAC is too low and Windows is always granting elevated rights. (The next question would be if he gets a prompt to elevate or the program just runs in admin-mode)

Comment: I believe if you are logged in as the user `Adminstrator` this is the normal behavior, you need do do as Ramhound says and create a normal user who is a member of the `Administrators` group.